# WPF ListView Performance really slow

Tags: wpf, listview, virtualization

My ListView performance is really slow, especially with sorting and filtering. Someone suggested to use virtualzation but I am using WrapPanel in my ListView. How to enhance the performance.

```
<ListView ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="liveGrid_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" Style="{DynamicResource LiveGridListView}"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent" x:Name="liveGrid" SelectionChanged="PlayerNodeSelected">

    <ListView.Resources>
         <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">9</sys:Double>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.MouseOver.Thumb" Color="#fff"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Pressed.Thumb" Color="#fff"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Thumb" Color="#fff"/>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
              <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
              <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
              <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                           <Grid Margin="0,10,20,0">
                                <controls:PlayerIsConnected Visibility="{Binding IsConnected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                                <controls:PlayerNeverConnected Visibility="{Binding IsPlayerNeveConnectedShown, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                                <controls:PlayerHadConnected Visibility="{Binding HasConnectedIsNotConnected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

                           </Grid>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
          </Style>
      </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <ListView.GroupStyle>

           <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                          <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>

                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,60,0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                             <Setter.Value>
                                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                             <Grid Height="28">
                                                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                  <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                       <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="White" FontFamily="{StaticResource BEGroteskMedium}" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                  </StackPanel>
                                                  <Border Grid.Column="1" Height="1" Margin="06,20,20,0" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
                                             </Grid>
                                        <ItemsControl>
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                      <WrapPanel Height="593" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                                 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        </ItemsControl>
                                        </StackPanel>

                               </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                         </Setter>

                     </Style>
                 </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>

             </GroupStyle>
         </ListView.GroupStyle>
         <ListView.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <WrapPanel  Orientation="Vertical"/>

              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemsPanel>
     </ListView>
```

Added my XAML code. It also has the grouping features. he listviewitem is a combination of images and text. I am displaying 4 rows in a column and based on the width there could be at max 20 items visible on the screen

Comment: how many rows does your listview display? also can you show us your xaml plz

Comment: added the code as well as some explanation about the code in the question itself

Comment: have you tried using a `VirtualizingWrapPanel`? It looks like it would not change much in the appearance of your ListItems.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: VirtualizingWrapPanel is not available in WPF only Virtualzing StackPanel and I cannot use Virtualizing StackPanel as it will not wrap the content

Comment: sry, I pasted the wrong link: http://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Format the XAML to the left.